# ActionBarCompat and Navigation Drawer icon size

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I've made some experiments with Navigation Drawer on the device 4.3. Then, I began to add navigation drawer in to the existing app that is for android 2.2 and higher. The app uses ActionBarCompat library. When I've added navigation drawer in this application everything works ok, except for navigation drawer icon near the app icon. The icon is not changing its size when drawer opens, it stays always full sized.

[closed drawer http://mobitronika.com/temp/Screenshot_2013-09-04-11-07-29.png](http://mobitronika.com/temp/Screenshot_2013-09-04-11-07-29.png)

Comment: Are you syncing state in `onPostCreate()` and did you added the drawer toggle to the nav drawer? Works flawlessly for me.

Comment: which code are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**ActionBarDrawerToggle**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).

like in **[this tutorial](http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2013/05/creating-navigation-drawer.html)** by Gabriele Mariotti.